# Why does this cast always fail? UE4

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I have an ai spawner BP and inside I want to call an event by timer to increase the characters walk speed after 10s, however the cast always fails. I have tried casting to the enemy and also tried to make an enemy ref object variable but still no luck. Any idea why I cant get it?

[image]

Comment: can you do a IsA check to see if the character is even of type Zombie_TD_char?

Comment: GetPlayerCharacter with Player Index (0) always gets the local APlayerController (you) and returns the assigned APawn. That is probably not your spawned zombie. Instead of GetPlayerCharacter. Where is this code? Is it in the spawner or in the spawned actor? Because, you maybe want to move it into the spawned actor instead.

Answer (score 1):

`GetPlayerCharacter` returns the current "Player Character" Object; this is the object the player's `PlayerController` is controlling, not an spawned AI Zombie.

The cast fails because the object going in is not of the type you are trying to cast it to.

Casting doesn't "Get" you an object that you cast to. It can refine the code context for an item that *is* of that type already.

If you want to get a reference to the zombie to change its walk speed, you need to hold onto a reference of it after spawning to  run it into this code.